# Interfacing NAND flash to a microcontroller

Tags: programming, nand-flash

I have a MP3 player with Samsung's nand flash chip (2GB), I want to connect that chip to microcontroller and read, write or list files and directories as we do with arduino SD Card Library. Your help is appreciated very much.

Thanks in advance.

[UPDATE]

hey guys I found out how to do it. I'm doing it with elm-chan FatFs library, everything is written for you just you've to implement low level diskio functions and your get to go. Check out the official site: http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html

Comment: Read the data sheet.

Comment: if your device is not an SD card, then the arduino sd card libraries won't help you at all. And your device is not an SD card.

Comment: "Samsung's NAND flash chip" <- Samsung has produced thousands of different flashes, and they work very differently. You'll have to do a lot more research than that!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately for you, this is not a free design house, homework-writing service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your questions shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post sure doesn't, I'm afraid. Please either revise your question showing your work so far or delete it if you find Internet searches give you your answer anyway. Again, welcome.

Comment: Sorry about my unclear question. I have already googled and found some info. The nand flash ic is K9GAG08UOE. I found that to read and write to flash we need a flash file system. YAFFS seems to be useful but I don't know how to interface the flash to MCU. I need some guide please. Thank you.

Comment: I was not able to find a diagram or schematic how to connect and communicate to flash chip and sorry again for being unclear. I'm on mobile device that's why I'm not able to tell all the things.

Comment: @varun really lame excuse. You want help, so write a good question. If you can't do that on your device, find a PC with a keyboard and start typing.

Comment: Your question reminds me of [this](http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/facebook/000/572/078/d6d.jpg). How do you interface a flash chip with an MCU? Well, connect them together, write flash drivers and a file system an you're done!

Answer (score 2):

Your K9GAG08UOE seems to have an 8 bit parallel data bus. You'll need to

- read the datasheet on the timing requirements of that, then
- you'll need to find a microcontroller that can interface on an 8 bit  parallel bus (you could also bit-bang on 8 GPIO lines, but that will   be horribly slow, and possibly not even meet the timing requirements), and then
- you'd design a circuit board that connects the 8 data lines of the NAND flash to that controller on the MCU, and also offers power, the read/write flags and so on,
- you'll need to be able to use the device as the flash memory it is, which would then enable you to pick an operating system (writing one sounds like a bad idea) that
- you'll need to write a hardware driver for your flash, and only then the OS could employ a file system on that device,
- you would then use to interface with the memory to give you a notion of *files* on that, and then
- you'd write a software for that OS that does something interesting with the memory and the files it stores.

Embedded development is not like application development on a PC or android device - there's no "driver", no "ready to be done exactly like this and that". You'll have to design all this yourself!

Comment: Thank you very much, then how such a small MP3 player is able to do that.

Comment: @varun what do you think? Implementing each of the bullet points above.

Comment: OK. Do we have any open source file system for nand flash

Comment: @varun please read my answer. This is **all** specific to the hardware you have. You **will have to** design this on your own.

Comment: Ok thank you. One last thing can you link me to a nand flash ic with SPI communication mode. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like I'm bothering you very much. Sorry and thank you for your help.

Comment: It can be done with elm-chan FatFs and you just have to implement low level diskio functions. It is the right way to do it.